# Symfony2 and DQL

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I'm running this DQL statement:

```
return $this->getEntityManager()
    ->createQuery("SELECT s FROM Bundle:table s WHERE s.title LIKE '%:search%'")
    ->setParameter('search', $search)
    ->getResult();
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use variable substitution like that. Try this:

```
return $this->getEntityManager()
    ->createQuery("SELECT s FROM Bundle:table s WHERE s.title LIKE :search")
    ->setParameter('search', "%" . $search . "%")
    ->getResult();
```

Comment: Yeah, I realized when I was debugging, it was stripping away the `%`. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently `Bundle:table` is not a correct reference to a bundle and an entity in your project. Check the spelling and camelCase of your Bundle / entity (or Entity ?) name.